# Remove Tensorflow print INFO (xxxx is not in all_model_checkpoint_paths. Manually adding it.)

Tags: tensorflow

when I set Three saver by ***tf.train.Saver()*** in TF,

```
saver1 = tf.train.Saver(max_to_keep= None, keep_checkpoint_every_n_hours= 2)
saver2 = tf.train.Saver(max_to_keep= 1000, keep_checkpoint_every_n_hours= 2)
saver3 = tf.train.Saver(max_to_keep= 1000, keep_checkpoint_every_n_hours= 2)
```

it shows this annoying information in the console

```
INFO:tensorflow:/home/cine/Documents/TF_Image/00000NewSim/Conv3_6_18_6_3174_2More/train2/model.ckpt-1 is not in all_model_checkpoint_paths. Manually adding it.
```

what I want to know is how to remove this information. Because I guess there are a lot of checking in here.
The reason why I use the ***max_to_keep*** parameter is because I want to save more parameters set of my model with different steps.

because I don't know when my model is fit, overfit or underfit.

I have to keep more parameter model sets. then evaluate them and select the best.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just an info and not a warning which happens if you set `max_to_keep= None`.
You can ignore it or set `max_to_keep` to a number higher than the epochs you expect.